# Unable to connect and get postgres data from cron scheduler job

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, crontrigger

I am looking for automatic postgres database connection when job is triggered. I am unable to connect to postgres database and get the booklist.

I tried to call a postgres database table called book_tbl with two columns id and name from MemberClassService as follows

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class MemberClassService {
    private ClassRepository classRepository;
    private MemberRepository memberRepository;
    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepository;
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("SampleLogger");

    public MemberClassService(ClassRepository classRepository, MemberRepository memberRepository,
            BookRepository bookRepository) {
        this.classRepository = classRepository;
        this.memberRepository = memberRepository;
        this.bookRepository = bookRepository;
    } 

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = true)

public void classStats() {

List<Book> booksList = bookRepository.findAll();

log.info("Books List sieze:::"+booksList.size());

Map<String, Integer> bookMap = booksList.stream()

.collect(Collectors.toMap(Book::getName, c -> 0));



}
}
```

I added following properites to application.properites file

```
#Postgres db2

spring.book.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/periphery_old

spring.book.datasource.username=postgres

spring.book.datasource.password=postgres

spring.book.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

I created following classes for it.

```
package com.gitlab.johnjvester.jpaspec.repository;

 

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

 

import com.gitlab.johnjvester.jpaspec.web.model.Book;

 

@Repository

public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor {

 

}

 
package com.gitlab.johnjvester.jpaspec.repository;

import com.gitlab.johnjvester.jpaspec.domain.MemberClass;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;

import java.util.List;

public interface ClassRepository extends JpaRepository<MemberClass, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor {
    List<MemberClass> findAllByNameContainsIgnoreCase(String searchString);
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I am unable to connect to postgres db to fetch list of books in classStats method.

Comment: The program by default runs cron job.At the moment when job triggers i am trying to fetch the data from postgres.Here i am unable to connect and get the books list.

Comment: The first to catch my eye, I think the `datasource` definition links in your `application.properties` file are wrong, unless you have a special configuration. **If there are any, we can debug them if you add them to your question.**